# Java 'factory' classes of extended objects

Tags: java, factory, extends

In Java, say I have an object called 'PERSON' that extends 'MESH'. Let's say that in the MESH class (or another class) I have a static method that creates an instance of a MESH. For Example:

```
Mesh m = Mesh.createMesh(parameters)
```

Now let's say I have the class Person... How can I use the factory to create the "mesh" part of the person?

```
Person p = Mesh.createMesh(parameters)
```

I undestand that the reference p cannot point to an object that doesn't have a Person's properties, but I want to somehow have the 'mesh' part of the person reuse that code from the 'factory' method.

I hope I made that clear...

Answer (score 2):

In your `Person` class, you could have a static factory method `createPerson(parameters)` which calls `createMesh(parameters)` and then creates a `Person` object based on the `Mesh` returned from `createMesh(parameters)`. For example:

```
public class Person extends Mesh {
    public static Person createPerson(... parameters) {
        Mesh mesh = createMesh(parameters);
        // now create the Person instance using details from the mesh object
        return new Person(mesh, parameters);  // or whatever method of creating your Person object that you need to perform
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem I see with this approach is that `Person.createMesh(.. parameters)` is still present in the Person class. I would recommend implementing factory classes separate from the Perso` and Mesh objects (i.e. MeshFactory and PersonFactory)

Comment: I would too, but the OP said it was the same class, so I used that in my demonstration. Also, `return new Person(mesh, parameters)` is only a placeholder for whatever method OP wants to use to create the Person object.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing to work cleanly, you need to be using composition rather than inheritance. That is a person should have a mesh, rather than be a mesh.

```
public static Person() {
   public final Mesh mesh;
   public Person(Mesh mesh) {
      this.mesh = mesh;
   }
}
```

Then you can write `Person p = new Person(Mesh.createMesh(...));`.

If you really want a Person to be a Mesh. Then you need something like:

```
public static class Mesh {
   protected Mesh(MeshParameters params) {
     ...
   }

   public static Mesh createMesh(MeshParameters params) {
     return new Mesh(params);
   }
}

public static Person extends Mesh {

   protected Person(MeshParameters params) {
      super(params);
      ...
   }

   public static Person createPerson(MeshParameters) {
      return new Person(params);
   }
}
```

Then you can use `Person p = Person.createPerson(...)`.

Comment: You forgot the static keyword in createPerson and createMesh

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, `Mesh.createMesh()` must delegate to a constructor for `Mesh` (or a constructor for a subclass, which delegates to the constructor for `Mesh`. You could make that constructor protected, and use that protected constructor in the `Person` constructor:

```
public class Person extends Mesh {
  private Person(Parameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);
    // do more here
  }

  public static Person create(Parameters parameters) {
    return new Person(parameters);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since we don't know how `createMesh` works, we can't assume it delegates to a constructor that does everything. It could just as easily create a empty Mesh object and then call lots of methods or set lots of attributes on it.

Comment: @Jason in that case, you extract out a protected method in Mesh that calls those setters. Without more details, it's hard to.make other recommendations.